# How to use AzureChatOpenAI instead of ChatOpenAI

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, azure-openai

In this function I want to use AzureChatOpenAI instead of ChatOpenAI tu be able to use the api keys only from azure ai
but when I try to replace it with AzureChatOpenAI it gives me this error:

```
raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}
```

```
def load_chain():
    prompt_template = """You are a helpful assistant for questions.

    {context}

    Question: {question}
    Answer here:"""
    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])

    retriever = AzureCognitiveSearchRetriever(content_key="content", top_k=10)
    

    chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=ChatOpenAI(),
        memory=memory,
        retriever=retriever,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT},
    )
    return chain
```

I tried to write it like

```
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=AzureChatOpenAI(
        openai_api_version="2023-05-15",
        azure_deployment="your-deployment-name",
         ),
        memory=memory,
        retriever=retriever,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": PROMPT},
    )
```

but gave me the error

Comment: did you set a "your-deployment-name" correctly, to the value of the deployment of your model in Azure OPenAI?